# How to set refresh date of a materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

When I create a materialized view today (2019-10-31) by using the piece of code below I expect to see the next refresh date 1st of November at 7 o'clock. However the next refresh date seems totally irrelevant it says it is today and 2 minutes later after creating the mat. view.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW XYZ
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE  
ON DEMAND 
START WITH SYSDATE
NEXT add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH'),1) + 7/24
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
SELECT * FROM  ABC;
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
start with (sysdate) next  last_day(trunc(sysdate,'MM'))+ 31/24 )
```